# Defining a gap between symbols on a line

Tags: geotools

I can't change the gaps between symbols on a line.

```
sf.graphicStroke(symbols, 
   ff.literal(symFillOpacity), 
   ff.literal(symSize), 
   ff.literal(0),      // rotation 
   sf.anchorPoint(ff.literal(0.5), ff.literal(0.5)),
   sf.displacement(ff.literal(0),ff.literal(0)), 
   ff.literal(3),      // initial gap
   ff.literal(500.0)); //gap
```

I'm able to change the rotation of the symbol, but what ever values I put in "initial gap" and "gap" nothing will change. I've tried with values from 0.5 to 500 but the symbols are repeated in the same way.

Test After Ian's comments:
I tried this but nothing is drawn, I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

```
    public static Style createLineStyle(
        Color outlineColor, 
        float lineOpacity, 
        String lineWidth, 
        String lineStyle, 
        String labelField, 
        Font labelFont, 
        Color txtColor, 
        float txtOpacity, 
        String symWellKnownName,
        Color SymLineColor,
        float symLineWidth,
        Color symFillColor,
        float symFillOpacity,
        float symLineOpacity,
        float symSize,
        String symRotAttribute,
        String minScale, 
        String maxScale, boolean addSymbol
        ) {
    StyleFactory sf = CommonFactoryFinder.getStyleFactory();
    FilterFactory ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory();
    List<GraphicalSymbol> symbols = new ArrayList<>();
    symbols.add(sf.createMark(ff.literal(symWellKnownName), 
        sf.createStroke(ff.literal(SymLineColor), 
        ff.literal(1)),
        sf.createFill(ff.literal(symFillColor)), 
        ff.literal(symSize), 
        ff.literal(0)/*rot*/));
    GraphicStroke gs = sf.graphicStroke(symbols, 
        ff.literal(1.0) /*transp*/, 
        ff.literal(symSize) /*size*/, 
        ff.literal(0) /* rotation*/, 
        sf.anchorPoint(ff.literal(0.5),ff.literal(0.5)) /*pivot-punkt*/, 
        sf.displacement(ff.literal(0),ff.literal(0)) /*displacement*/, 
        ff.literal(0) /*initial gap*/,
        ff.literal(1.0) /*gap*/);
    StyleBuilder sb = new StyleBuilder(sf);
    Stroke stroke = sf.stroke(gs, 
            ff.literal("#0000ff"), 
            gs.getOpacity(), 
            ff.literal(lineWidth),
            null, 
            null, 
            new float[] { 6, 3 },//dash array
            ff.literal(2));
    LineSymbolizer ls = sf.lineSymbolizer("Lines", ff.literal("the_geom"), null, null, stroke, null);
    FeatureTypeStyle fts = sb.createFeatureTypeStyle(ls);
    Style style = sb.createStyle();
    style.featureTypeStyles().add(fts);
    SLDTransformer transformer = new SLDTransformer();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    transformer.setIndentation(2);
    try {
        transformer.transform(style, bos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String style1 = bos.toString();
    System.out.println(style1);
    return style;
}
```

The printout of the from the style above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sld:UserStyle xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" mlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
  <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
  <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
  <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
  <sld:Rule>
     <sld:LineSymbolizer>
        <sld:Geometry>
          <ogc:Literal>the_geom</ogc:Literal>
        </sld:Geometry>
        <sld:Stroke>
           <sld:GraphicStroke>
              <sld:Graphic>
                 <sld:Mark>
                     <sld:WellKnownName>Cross</sld:WellKnownName>
                     <sld:Fill>
                        <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#FF3333</sld:CssParameter>
                     </sld:Fill>
                     <sld:Stroke/>
                  </sld:Mark>
                     <sld:Size>22.0</sld:Size>
                     <sld:AnchorPoint>
                        <sld:AnchorPointX>0.5</sld:AnchorPointX>
                        <sld:AnchorPointY>0.5</sld:AnchorPointY>
                     </sld:AnchorPoint>
                  </sld:Graphic>
               </sld:GraphicStroke>
               <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#0000ff</sld:CssParameter>
               <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">1px</sld:CssParameter>
               <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-dashoffset">2</sld:CssParameter>
               <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray">6.0 3.0</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Stroke>
         </sld:LineSymbolizer>
      </sld:Rule>
   </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
</sld:UserStyle>
```

This test is with my original code (it draws the line and the symbols but I can't change the gap):

```
    public static Style createLineStyle(Color outlineColor, float lineOpacity, String lineWidth, String lineStyle,
        String labelField, Font labelFont, Color txtColor, float txtOpacity, String symWellKnownName,
        Color SymLineColor, float symLineWidth, Color symFillColor, float symFillOpacity, float symLineOpacity,
        float symSize, String symRotAttribute, String minScale, String maxScale, boolean addSymbol) {
    float[] dashArray = null;
    if (lineStyle != null && !lineStyle.equals("null")) {
        String[] sp = lineStyle.split(" ");
        dashArray = new float[sp.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < sp.length; i++) {
            dashArray[i] = Float.parseFloat(sp[i].replace("px", ""));
        }
    }
    Stroke stroke = sf.createStroke(ff.literal(outlineColor),
                    ff.literal(lineWidth),
                    ff.literal(lineOpacity),
                    null,
                    null, dashArray, null, null, null);
    LineSymbolizer lineIcon = null;
    if (addSymbol) {
        Stroke strokeIcon = sf.createStroke(null, null);
        List<GraphicalSymbol> symbols = new ArrayList<>();
        String fcolor = toHTMLColor(symFillColor);
        String ocolor = toHTMLColor(SymLineColor);
        Mark mark = sf.createMark(ff.literal(symWellKnownName),
            sf.createStroke(ff.literal(ocolor), 
            ff.literal(symLineWidth)), 
            sf.createFill(ff.literal(fcolor)),
            ff.literal(symSize), ff.literal(0));
        symbols.add(mark);
        GraphicStroke gs = null;
        try {
            gs = sf.graphicStroke(symbols,
                 ff.literal(symFillOpacity), 
                 ff.literal(symSize), 
                 ff.literal(0),
                 sf.anchorPoint(ff.literal(0.5), ff.literal(0.5)), 
                 sf.displacement(ff.literal(0), ff.literal(0)),
                 ff.literal(0), ff.literal(1.0));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        strokeIcon.setGraphicStroke(gs);
        lineIcon = sf.createLineSymbolizer(strokeIcon, null);
    }
    LineSymbolizer lineSym = sf.createLineSymbolizer(stroke, null);
    Style style = wrapSymbolizers(lineIcon, lineSym);
    SLDTransformer transformer = new SLDTransformer();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    transformer.setIndentation(3);
    try {
        transformer.transform(style, bos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String style1 = bos.toString();
    System.out.println(style1);
    return style;
}
```

Here is the sld printout of the style above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sld:UserStyle xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
  <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
  <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
     <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
     <sld:Rule>
        <sld:LineSymbolizer>
           <sld:Stroke>
              <sld:GraphicStroke>
                 <sld:Graphic>
                    <sld:Mark>
                       <sld:WellKnownName>Cross</sld:WellKnownName>
                       <sld:Fill>
                          <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#FF3366</sld:CssParameter>
                       </sld:Fill>
                       <sld:Stroke/>
                    </sld:Mark>
                    <sld:Size>22.0</sld:Size>
                    <sld:AnchorPoint>
                       <sld:AnchorPointX>0.5</sld:AnchorPointX>
                       <sld:AnchorPointY>0.5</sld:AnchorPointY>
                    </sld:AnchorPoint>
                 </sld:Graphic>
              </sld:GraphicStroke>
           </sld:Stroke>
        </sld:LineSymbolizer>
        <sld:LineSymbolizer>
           <sld:Stroke>
              <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#4F4F4F</sld:CssParameter>
              <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">2px</sld:CssParameter>
           </sld:Stroke>
        </sld:LineSymbolizer>
     </sld:Rule>
  </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
</sld:UserStyle>
```

Comment: If your mark is 22px in size your dash array must be 22 or more or nothing will be drawn. So 6 is too small. There is no need for an anchor point or displacement in the graphic stroke

Comment: I copy-pasted your code with your hardcoded parameters into my function (I don't do anything else), but nothing is drawn. The only extra thing I do is: return style;

Comment: Depending on your `symbSize` you need to change `new float[] { 6, 3 },//dash array` so that the first number is larger than `symbSize`

Comment: I've tried your code with sym-size 6 and dash array { 6, 3 } I also tried with sym size 6 and { 7, 3 } but nothing is drawn.

Comment: did you also remove the anchor point and displacement like I did?

Comment: Yes, I copy/pasted your code. Do I have to handle this style in another way when it's created, compared to mine?

Answer (score 2):

GeoTools will only draw the `Graphic` fits in the dash (the first number in the dash-array) so you need to provide an sufficiently large dash in the dash array, which as far as I can tell you need to set on the `Stroke` not the `GraphicStroke`. To be honest the `StyleFactory` is pretty unfriendly compared to `StyleBuilder` but that doesn't seem to handle `GraphicStrokes`.

I get a line of green circles with this code:

```
StyleFactory sf = CommonFactoryFinder.getStyleFactory();
FilterFactory ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory();
List<GraphicalSymbol> symbols = new ArrayList<>();
symbols.add(sf.createMark(ff.literal("circle"), sf.createStroke(ff.literal("#ff0000"), ff.literal(1)),
    sf.createFill(ff.literal("#00ff00")), ff.literal(6), ff.literal(0)));
GraphicStroke gs = sf.graphicStroke(symbols, ff.literal(1.0), ff.literal(6.0), ff.literal(0), // rotation
    null, null, null, null);
StyleBuilder sb = new StyleBuilder(sf);
Stroke stroke = sf.stroke(gs, ff.literal("#0000ff"), gs.getOpacity(), ff.literal(2), null, null,
    new float[] { 6, 3 }, ff.literal(2));
LineSymbolizer ls = sf.lineSymbolizer("Lines", ff.literal("geom"), null, null, stroke, null);
FeatureTypeStyle fts = sb.createFeatureTypeStyle(ls);
Style style = sb.createStyle();
style.featureTypeStyles().add(fts);
SLDTransformer transformer = new SLDTransformer();
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
transformer.setIndentation(2);

transformer.transform(style, bos);
String style1 = bos.toString();
System.out.println(style1);
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your code but nothing is drawn and there are no exceptions or error codes. I have updated my original post with the tests and printouts.